How to ignore trailing whitespace?
Say a SQL table contains a column of char(10), and a record contains the value "ABC" in that column. Entity Framework will pass ABC        ("ABC" with 7 trailing spaces) when asked for the value.
Is there a way to ask Entity Framework to ignore trailing whitespace when getting the value of a column of type char, essentially having EF treat it like a varchar instead?
A quick look at the methods available in the fluent API has yielded no obvious solutions.Removing entity.Property(e => e.CharColumn).IsFixedLength() does not produce the desired effect of trimming trailing whitespace.
Changing the type of the column from char to varchar in the SQL database is not an option in my use case as it could interfere with other programs beyond my control which read this table.

Trim yourself after data retrieved? char 10 means there are 10 chars not 10 or less so i would assume there is nothing build in.

Here are some ways todo it. Might be something in there for either database first, model first EF or EF Core etc.

EF is correct. A char(10) field always has 10 characters. The column doesn't contain ABC, it contains ABC       . Either remove IsFixedLength() and use a varchar field or add explicit trimming to your application.

Why do you want to trim the actual value? Is it for display purposes? Search? Comparison? It matters. For searches and comparison, SQL Server will pad any value less than 10 characters to the full 10 char length, so ABC is equal to ABC       . No amount of trimming will change this. If you want to trim for display, it's better to do so in a ViewModel or View

You could consider introducing a new varchar column in which you have logic controlling whether or not to trim the characters when saving to the db

Tell us why you want this

Instead of using an auto property in your entity class, you can create one yourself trimming the values.
private string _myProp;
public string MyProp
{
    get => _myProp?.TrimEnd();
    set => _myProp = value;
}

Be careful by doing it in the setter. I am not sure about Entity Framework, but EF Core directly assigns the values to the backing field if it finds one, bypassing the setter. Assuming Entity Framework does not bypass the setter:
private string _myProp;
public string MyProp
{
    get => _myProp;
    set => _myProp = value?.TrimEnd();
}


It's not EF that bypasses the setter. In all databases fixed length fields are space-padded - or at least they should be, according to the SQL standard. SQL server will store ABC       . During comparisons string values will be padded to the field length, so ABC is equal to ABC       .

If the OP wants to trim so they can search for just ABC, they'll realize there's no change

@PanagiotisKanavos my solution fixes the problem in the front-end. SQL-Server ignores trailing white spaces when doing comparisons: fiddle

My point is that we don't know the actual problem. If that's just for the UI, this will work. If the OP wants to exclude ABC        when searching for ABC, it won't
